# The divisibility of $a^p-1$ by $a-1$ and by $(a-1)^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I was working my way through some number theoretic proofs and being a newbie am stuck on this problem :

> Let a $\geq$ 2 and p be any positive integers , then prove that :
>
> - $(a-1) \mid(a^p - 1) $
> - $ (a-1)^2 \mid (a^p - 1) $ iff $ (a-1) \mid p $

***My Attempt (Inadequate):***

> **First Part :**
>
> - $(a-1) \mid(a^p - 1) $
> - We know that $(a^p - 1)$ can be written as $(a-1).(a^{p-1} + \cdots + 1)$
> - $\Rightarrow$ $(a^p - 1)$ is of the form (a-1).$\lambda$
> - $\Rightarrow$ (a-1) $\mid$ $(a^p - 1)$
>
> Hence , Proved
>
> ===========================================================
>
> **Second Part:**
>
> I have absolutely no clue and that is why ask for a hint and not a solution

***My Question :***

> I am unable to make any concrete progress . Even a decent hint would be acceptable so that I can build on that ...

Comment: The first one is high-school algebra: surely you’ve seen a factorization of $a^n-b^n$?

Comment: By the way, there is nothing about primes in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: The first can be proven easily by induction on $p$.

The second you can prove by showing (again by induction on $p$) that $$a^p-1\equiv (a-1)p\pmod {(a-1)^2}.$$

(Of course, this second proof could be used to prove the first part.)

Comment: Hi , @ThomasAndrews , thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: using the binomial theorem,
$$a^p-1=\sum_{k=1}^p \binom pk (a-1)^k\ .$$

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea.
$(a-1)k=a^p-1 \\ (a-1)k=a^p-1+a^{p+1}-a^{p+1}$
Play with this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a-1=d$

So, $a^p-1=(1+d)^p-1$

Using Binomial Expansion, $(1+d)^p-1\equiv1+dp-1\pmod{d^2}$

which will be $\equiv0\pmod{d^2}\iff p\equiv0\pmod d$

Comment: @pranav, The operator is not $=,$ but $\equiv$ the following $p+1-2=p-1$ contain $d^2$ as a multiplicand

Answer (score 0):

Another form

Consider $p(x) =x^p -1 =(x-1)(x^{p-1} + ... + 1)$, now $p(a) = (a-1)(a^{p-1} + ...+1)$
here we have the first step.

Now we consider that $g(x) = x^{p-1} + ...+1$ and take $g(1) = p$, then by remainder theorem we have g(x) = (x-1)q(x) + p, where q(x) is a polynomial and take 
$$g(a) = (a-1)q(a) + p$$ and how $(a-1)|p$, we have $(a-1)|(a^{p-1} + ...+1)$.

Therore $(a-1)^2|a^p -1$ if $(a-1)|p$

For the only if, is easy with the above fact